# Code not working for dismissing Keyboard

Tags: swift, xcode, keyboard

I am trying to create code for dismissing the Keyboard when touching outside the keyboard or when pressing the return button. But it is ofcourse not working :D That is why I am asking here. How can I make it work? It doesn't give an error but it is just not responding.

If there are simpler solution, then that is also welcome to provide.

Thank you for your time and answer!

Here is my full code:

```
import UIKit

class EntryViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var UserEmailAdresInput: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var UserPasswordInput: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var UserPasswordInputRepeated: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var UserSignUp: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.UserEmailAdresInput.delegate = self
        self.UserPasswordInput.delegate = self
        self.UserPasswordInputRepeated.delegate = self


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBAction func SignUp(_ sender: Any) {

        let UserEmail = UserEmailAdresInput.text;
        let UserPassword = UserPasswordInput.text;
        let UserPasswordRepeated = UserPasswordInputRepeated.text;

        //Hide Keyboard upon Touch

        func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?){
            self.view.endEditing(true)
        }

        //Hide Keyboard upon Return Key
        func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            UserEmailAdresInput.resignFirstResponder()
            return (true)


        }

        //Check if fields are filled in correctly

        if(UserEmail?.isEmpty == true || UserPassword?.isEmpty == true || UserPasswordRepeated?.isEmpty == true){

            displayAlertMessage(userMessage: "Alle velden moeten ingevuld worden");
            return;

        }

        if(UserPassword != UserPasswordRepeated){

            displayAlertMessage(userMessage: "Wachtwoorden zijn niet gelijk");
            return;
        }

        //Store Data
        UserDefaults.standard.set(UserEmail, forKey: "UserEmail");
        UserDefaults.standard.set(UserPassword, forKey: "UserPassword");
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize();

        //SignUp Succesfull
        var Alert = UIAlertController(title:"Succesvol aangemeld!", message: "Ga naar je email inbox om je aanmelding te voltooien", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);

        let OkAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil);

        Alert.addAction(OkAction);
        self.present(Alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }

    func displayAlertMessage(userMessage:String){

        var Alert = UIAlertController(title:"Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);

        let OkAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil);

        Alert.addAction(OkAction);

        self.present(Alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

Comment: u r defining touhesBegan inside your func. It wont be called anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below UITextField Delegate method will use to resign your textfield on press on return button on keyboard.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            if textField == UserEmailAdresInput{
                 UserEmailAdresInput.resignFirstResponder()
            } else if textField == UserPasswordInput{
                 UserPasswordInput.resignFirstResponder()
            } else {
                 UserPasswordInputRepeated.resignFirstResponder()
            }
            return true
   }
```

and put your touchesBegan and textFieldShouldReturn method outside the signUp Method.